# Windows Server domain controller

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2012

For example I have 3 servers (DC-A a: offside server - main server, DC-B: local server and DC-C: offside) all running active directory. For the redundancy between the DC-A, DC-B and DC-C server. DC-B was set up as a new domain controller in an existing domain (dc a: offside server).
The question is if the DC-A is switched off, will the users still authenticate or use services such as file and print? Do I need to setup DNS on both DC-B and DC-C before removing completely the DC-A from the network?

Comment: `Do I need to setup DNS on both DC-B and DC-C`  Define "setup DNS".  By default, domain controllers run a DNS server.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have 3 DCs and one fails, you will need the following services available to keep Active Directory up and running:

1) A Running DHCP server.
To accomplish this, I recommend setting up a [failover DHCP Server](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831385(v=ws.11).aspx) on one of the other DCs.

2) DNS 
Configure your DHCP server to point to all your DCs.  By default, DNS gets installed with AD. [image]

In the event one of the DCs fail, as long as DHCP and DNS are available, your computers will continue to be able to login.  Printing and File sharing are another another story and for those, I recommend looking into setting up a [failover cluster](http://windowsitpro.com/windows-server-2012/windows-server-2012-building-two-node-failover-cluster) or a [DFS](https://mizitechinfo.wordpress.com/2013/08/21/step-by-step-deploy-dfs-in-windows-server-2012-r2/).

Comment: You should point out that the exact answer is: As long as the client is able to contact one of the AD-integrated DNS-servers and resolve the FQDN of the domain, the client is able to proceed with authentication. DHCP is a good idea, but not necessary.

Comment: NO DHCP running on these server

Comment: Was the question answered or are you looking for more information and if so could you please provide some more information.